# ELK - Get datetime from logs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

I am trying to get logs to Kibana using logstash and filebeats. I need to get log time from the log file. However kibana doesn't take data and time (which in the logs) as datetime. Instead in takes as string and cannot change format as well.
I have been trying with different time formats but no luck.
Appreciate your help
Here are the configurations.

logstash filter

```
filter {
grok {
match => {
"message" => "(?application_[^/])[^ ] [%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logTime}] %{LOGLEVEL:logLevel} %{GREEDYDATA:LogMessage}" }
}
}
```

sample logs

```
/yarn/container-logs/application_1621858977521_0151/container_1621858977521_0151_01_000004 [2021-06-28 02:38:10,542] INFO Started daemon with process name: 7796@slave1 (org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend)
/yarn/container-logs/application_1621858977521_0151/container_1621858977521_0151_01_000004 [2021-06-28 02:38:10,547] INFO Registered signal handler for TERM (org.apache.spark.util.SignalUtils)
/yarn/container-logs/application_1621858977521_0151/container_1621858977521_0151_01_000004 [2021-06-28 02:38:10,548] INFO Registered signal handler for HUP (org.apache.spark.util.SignalUtils)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply rename **logTime** to **timestamp**

```
filter {
grok {
match => {
"message" => "(?application_[^/])[^ ] [%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}] %{LOGLEVEL:logLevel} %{GREEDYDATA:LogMessage}" }
}
}
```